# How to get frame number from page table?

Tags: c, operating-system, virtual-memory

My understanding is that the page table is already specified somewhere in memory, so I just need the page number to get frame number so I can get the physical address. How do i implement the page table so I can look up the frame number?

Given a virtual address

```
page_number = (virtual >> page_bits);
page_offset = (virtual & page_size);
physical = page_table[page_number] + page_offset;
```

How is the page table implemented?

Comment: This is going to depend on your environment. There is no portable way to get a page table in C - you might be even be running on a platform without virtual addressing! I suggest looking up the specifics of your architecture and OS -- and chances are it won't let you access it from user mode.

Comment: Unless the page is locked  in physical memory there is no guarantee that it is in physical memory, or has not been swapped out and back in to a different location.   So reading the page table from user space is pointless.

Comment: So whats the best way to get the physical address if I cannot access the page table?